# Grabbing YUVY-camera as RGB device is slower than grabbing as YUVY and do the convertion to RGB afterwards

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing

I have two situations:

1. Open YUVY-camera in OpenCV as RGB device
2. Open YUVY-camera in V4L2 as native YUVY device and convert it to RGB via cv::cvtColor

The first one causes higher load on the cpu than the second one, and the question is why.
Here are my assumptions why this is the case for the different setups:

1. OpenCV wraps V4L2 and tells the V4L2 driver, that it should convert the image to RGB, while the converter in V4L2 is not capable of using SIMD instructions
2. V4L2 gets the image as native YUVY image and the convertion is done via the SIMD capable cv::cvtColor library

Are my assumptions correct, or do I have to search for other reasons why the two setups causes different load on the CPU?

**UPDATE:**
I just investigated the [cap.cpp](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/9c0a5523e4703508c58a587a47b26baae32810af/modules/videoio/src/cap.cpp) and it is possible that OpenCV uses any API but V4L, so my first assumption might be not fully correct.

Comment: this is very speculative... especially by focusing too much on V4L2. What is the correlation between SIMD instructions and lower cpu load? Isn't a faster instruction effective because it uses more from a cpu?

Comment: @UmNyobe By using the SIMD intrinsics the code should be (theoretically) as fast as the width of the instruction word.Thus, the CPU has more time to idle, so that the 'load' indicator under Linux should be lower. I just investigated both ways of opening and grabbing the images from the camera device. And the biggest impact from my point of view are the SIMD instructions in the conversion from YUVY to RGB.

Comment: Let me resume : *Faster instruction -> more idle time for the cpu* ? this is blatant simplification. Why do you get from 'load' indicator to cpu cycle without taking in consideration all the memory model in between? Is A being slower than B your issue? or is A using more cpu your issue? Please clarify and refrain from jumping too fast to conclusions.

Comment: @UmNyobe Ok, now I got you. Just as an information: I'm running the code on an embedded device with few CPU power. A produces "> 1" load on a single CPU, which slows down the whole process so that I get only 3 of 5 fps out of the camera. B runs with a load of 0.6 and I get full 5 of 5 fps. Thus, A using more CPU resources AND it is slower than B.

Comment: How do transport the data? early conversion cost `bpp(rgb)/bpp(yuvy)  = 3/2 = 150%` more traffic between camera engine and the next unit

Comment: The target format is always RGB, which is going to be processed by the next unit (which are disabled for both cases for evaluation). Thus, I only evaluate the processing until I have the image in RGB format in my program. The copying processes of the image in the program/APIs itself is nearly the same in the V4L2 and OpenCV pipeline and has in fact only minimal effect on the CPU load. Here, I do not perform a real "transportation" via e.g. sockets yet.